# Typescript: why does `let val: K extends K ? string : any = ""` not compile?

Tags: typescript, conditional-types

Within the context where some parametric Type `K` exists, and it is clear that `K extends string | number | symbol` the line

```
let val: K extends K ? string : any = ""
```

Gives a compiler error:

> TS2322: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'K extends K ? string : any'.

I would have expected this to compile, since `K extends K` should evaluate to true.
generally, isn't `true ? A : B` always inferred to be A ?
What's the problem here?

Answer (score 1):

If `K` can be *anything* it could very well be some very corner case like `never`, `void`, `unknown`, `any`. The TS type system is so large that I wouldn't dare doing the kind of assumption that "K always extends itself".

I still don't get the use case: if the compiler would be explicitly told to expect the expression `K extends K` to always evaluate to true, the whole expression would be useless, just short circuiting to `string`, isn't it?

Is there a use case or is it just for the sake of it?

IMHO the use of `extends` expressions should be normally reserved to return values and parameters: when you have to assign a value to a constant or variable, your right side should evaluate to some specific value, with a specific type.

Finally, if you just need the expression to compile, because later on you will overwrite the value, just add `as any` and call it a day.

Comment: Yes there is a Usecase, and this expression does not appear in my code litterally, but a type expression is resolved to this very expression.
particularly, i want typescript to ensure, that for some input object 'stateObject' and some key 'stateKey' it holds that stateObject[stateKey] has type string.
But maybe the whole usecase would be better suited for a question of its own.

Comment: I would think so. I think the corner you ended up should probably be addressed someway else. If you post another question, comment here. I would love to see the use case!

Comment: I'm in the process of writing the related post. However, I want to note (added it to the question) that `K extends string | number | symbol` is known in my context, so with that info - shouldn't typescript infer true?

Comment: my other SO question with the context:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66522410/correct-typing-for-react-typescript-input-component-for-mobx

Comment: I still don't understand the Problem. To get a hang of types, I think of them in terms of Sets. | is just set union, and extends is just the subset relation. It should hold that a | b extends a | b - why would that not be true?

Why would SomeType have to extend all three to make
SomeType extends (string | number | symbol) hold?

Comment: Look at it this way: if I give you a thing that is either a string or a number (but you don't know if it's either), and I ask you to give me something that extends it, you need to get something that is contemporary both a string and a number. You're not allowed to look inside the box, and tell me "oh, it's a string, so I'll get you just one string". The actual type (either A-string or B-number) will be bound later, so you can't decide if it's one or the other. So you need to extend both. In other words `A | B` assumes different behavior if its before or after the extends keyword.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229634/discussion-between-iari-and-a-chiesa).

Comment: So my current understanding is that K extends K should actually still evaluate to true.

Comment: actually, logically even never should extend never. subtyping should be reflexive