# Correct Typing for React/Typescript Input component for MobX

Tags: typescript, mobx-react, conditional-types

I would like to write a React Input component with Typescript for MobX that takes as its input props:

- a mobx store `stateObject`
- a key from that store `stateKey`

Typescript should enforce that `stateObject[stateKey]` is of type string.
That is, what the ExtraProps is supposed to take care of in the example below.
However, I cannot get the types to compile the way I expect them to, but get

> TS2322: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'K extends K ? string : any'.

[See my related SO post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66521952/typescript-why-does-let-val-k-extends-k-string-any-not-compile)

So the following is my approach:

```js
import React, {ChangeEvent, Component, InputHTMLAttributes} from "react";

type ExtraProps<T extends string | number | symbol, K extends T> = {
    stateKey: K,
    stateObject: { [k in T]: k extends K ? string : any }
}
type InputProps = Omit<InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>, "value" | "onChange">
type InputPropType<T extends string | number | symbol, K extends T> = InputProps & ExtraProps<T, K>

export class InputField<T extends string | number | symbol, K extends T> extends Component<InputPropType<T, K>, any> {
    constructor(props: InputPropType<T, K>) {
        super(props);
        this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this)
    }

    onChange(event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
        let val: K extends K ? string : any = event.target.value; // TS2322: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'K extends K ? string : any'.
        this.props.stateObject[this.props.stateKey] = val;
    }

    render() {
        let {stateKey, stateObject, ...props} = this.props;
        return <input {...props} value={stateObject[stateKey]} onChange={this.onChange}/>
    }
}
```

Now my questions would be:

- what is wrong with my types?
- Is this even a senisble route to achieve what I want, or is there a better approach?

Again, what I want is a managed input component that just reads/writes its value from/to the mobx store.

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this:

```
// TypeScript Voodoo. See:
// https://medium.com/dailyjs/typescript-create-a-condition-based-subset-types-9d902cea5b8c
// for details about how this works.
export type FilterFlags<Base, Condition> = { [Key in keyof Base]: Base[Key] extends Condition ? Key : never };
export type AllowedNames<Base, Condition> = FilterFlags<Base, Condition>[keyof Base];
```

The usage is:

```
type ExtraProps<T> = AllowedNames<T, string>;
type InputProps = Omit<InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>, "value" | "onChange">
// not really sure about this, but I don't think the original '&' makes sense:
type InputPropType<T> = InputProps | ExtraProps<T>;
```

Which gives you a union type with the list of string properties of type `K`.
You don't need the type `K`, you just need the type `T`, which is the type of your `stateObject` value.

Comment: I've tryed implementing it using
```type ExtraProps<T extends object, K extends AllowedNames<T, string>> = {
    stateKey: K,
    stateObject: T
}```

and I still get
`TS2322: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'T[K]'.` at the same position. can you give an example with the full code from above?